# Which idealogy states aatma (soul) doesn't exist; only paramatmaa (God) does?

Tags: theology

The ideology states all this world is His creation and it will die. God is beyond all this. It is difficult to understand for normal people. But I believe it.  It states we are mere lies. We will die.  He is the one who will remain forever.

I want to know the name of this ideology so that I can read more.Can you understand it belongs here because I don't know the answer. if I knew the answer I would have not even asked the question so how does it belong to Hinduism se I don't get it

Edit:

The ideology SAYS something like this: We are not Him.  We are mere lies. We were made by him.  I was a mere machine or a mere vastu (thing).  I was made to believe that I exist. There is no me that's gonna live forever.

Comment: Sure that this doesn't belong to hinduism?

Comment: i dont know which it belongs to thats why i am asking

Comment: Let's ask @PeterJ if e can help.

Comment: @christo183 - Always ready with an opinion, as you know. :) I know of no doctrine that matches the OPs description. It is a little vague so I'm having to guess precisely what is being asked. Those doctrines that deny individual souls are usually atheistic or claim that we are God and are immortal. Son of Thought mentions 'non-dualism' and this may be what the OP is groping towards. There is a vast literature. I'm reluctant to post a reading recommendation without more info but this would be be Middle Way Buddhism, Taoism, Sufism, Theosophy, Cristian mysticism, advaita Vedanta etc.   . .

Comment: It would help if the question was expanded a little to let us know where the questioner is coming from, in order to make relevant reading suggestions. .

Comment: @Sandeep Gulati: "All this world is His creation and it will die.' ~ This is not Advaita Vedanta.  Only your main question seems to Advaita. You may add more details and edit again.

Comment: belongs on Hinduism SE......

Comment: This does belong here as I don't know the answer

Answer (score 3):

In your question, I think there is a mix-up of ideologies.

Read the details regarding Advaita in the first answer to this question:  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/dvaita-vs-advaita-vs-vishistadvaita-vs-shuddhadvaita-vs-any-other

> According to Advaita Vedanta, Brahman is the highest
>   Reality,[67][138][139] That which is unborn and unchanging,[138][140]
>   and "not sublatable",[67] and cannot be superseded by a still higher
>   reality.[141][note 12][note 13] Other than Brahman, everything else,
>   including the universe, material objects and individuals, are
>   ever-changing and therefore maya. Brahman is Paramarthika Satyam,
>   "Absolute Truth",[156] and the true Self, pure consciousness ... the only 
>   Reality (sat), since It is untinged by difference, the mark of ignorance, and > since
>   It is the one thing that is not sublatable".[67]

For more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta